# vb.net call subroutine from form3

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have three Forms; Formone Mdi form, Formtwo non Mdi form and  Formthree the child of Formtwo

I want when Formthree closes, to call a subroutine (RefreshData()) in Formtwo, this is what I have but not working. Thanks

```
        Dim formone As New MainWindow
        Dim formtwo As New AppFormData
        Dim formthree As New UpdateAppForm
        formtwo.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
        formtwo.RefreshData()
        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
```

Comment: `not working` is the least useful way to describe the problem. Please read [Ask] because this question is not working

Comment: @Plutonix, I have TextBox in formtwo which shows number of records, I expect when RefreshData() sub is  called the TextBox should show changes. The method above does not show any changes i.e Nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

First, you make sure that `formtwo`'s `RefreshData()` is declared as `Public` so it can be accessed from a different form rather than the form where it is created.

Like:

```
Public Sub RefreshData()
...
End Sub
```

Then regarding how you call it when `formthree` closes, you can use the `Form_Closing` event.

```
Private Sub formthree_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
     formtwo.RefreshData()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Crush Sundae, formtwo's RefreshData() is public already, I want to call RefreshData() sub, for example, when  I Insert data in the database using formthree and then call RefreshData() sub  and finally  close formthree. The purpose of RefreshData() sub is to update number of records in the TextBox in formtwo.

Comment: So what still seems to be the problem?

Comment: it does not update the TextBox and does not show errors..however if I set the startup form to be formtwo in the Visual Studio, it's working. if the Setup form is formone which is an Mdi form it does not work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better design will be to use events. This approach will work gracefully if you make Formthree as child of any other form as it is not depending on this parentform. Declare the event in Formthree and consume it in parentform i.e. Formtwo

```
Public Class Formthree

    Public Event CallMethod()

    Private Sub Formthree_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        RaiseEvent CallMethod()
    End Sub

    .
    .
    .

End Class

Public Class Formtwo

    Private WithEvents frm3 As Formthree

    .
    .
    .

    Private Sub frm3_CallMethod() Handles frm3.CallMethod
        RefreshData()
    End Sub
End Class
```